# PDF not loading webkit view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

Webkit view is not loading my pdf file when i am passing the website  url and moreover i have also allowed the HTTPS protocol.

```
PDFVIEWER.Swift
import UIKit
import WebKit
class ReaderViewController: UIViewController {
    var urlstring : String?
    @IBOutlet weak var WEBVIEW: WKWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(urlstring!)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath : "https://www.hdfcbank.com/assets/pdf/Rewards_Catalogue.pdf")
        let request = URLRequest(url : url)
        WEBVIEW.load(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this code giving any error? If so, what line?

Comment: no just not loading the pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the **fileURLWithPath** as you are not using the local URL. It refers to the local file or directory at path and that path should be a valid system path, and must not be an empty path.

Just replace the **fileURLWithPath** with **string** to your variable **url** like the below code.

```
let url = URL(string : "https://www.hdfcbank.com/assets/pdf/Rewards_Catalogue.pdf")
    let request = URLRequest(url : url!)
    webView.load(request)
```

Comment: I am saving the file internally in my local storage also and when [passing that path its working well on simulator but not on iphone .Can u help.?I think that it is not able to d\got to that path . Dont know y !

Comment: Did you use **URLSessionDownloadTask** ?Do you copy from tmp to document directory using file manager and read file locally?

Comment: yes exactly i have downloaded the file successfully using Alamofire. I am getting the path for the same also . But when i m using simulator file is successfully displayed but on iphone it is getting the path but not able to display the file locally on webkitview

Comment: would you paste the device full path with file name here?

Answer (score 0):

Convert pdf file to NSData after that load on webview.

```
      NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",newDateString]];
               NSLog(@"%@",finalPath);
         NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
         [data writeToURL:url atomically:YES];

         dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.25 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             [webView loadData:data
                      MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
              textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
                       baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];

         });
```

Comment: IF you don't know swift , so plz some RND.